# Should I persist data objects in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, state, greendao, screen-rotation

I'm using [greenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) in my android app to display a list of objects in a `RecyclerView`. I have a subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter` that takes a list of objects which are greenDAO entities.

What I do in `onCreate` is:

1. Create an instance of my adapater passing `null` for my list. This is just to make the adapter known to the `RecyclerView` below.
2. Initialize the `RecyclerView` with layout and adapter.
3. Call a method that asynchronously queries the data using greenDAO and upon success updates the adapter with the actual list of objects so they are displayed.

This is the relevant code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mListAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(null);
    mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
    refreshItems();
}

public void refreshItems()
{
    AsyncSession asyncSession = ((App)getApplication()).getDaoSession().startAsyncSession();
    asyncSession.setListenerMainThread(new AsyncOperationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(final AsyncOperation operation)
        {
            if (operation.isCompletedSucessfully())
                mListAdapter.setItems((List<Item>) operation.getResult());
        }
    });

    asyncSession.loadAll(Item.class);
}
```

This works pretty well. Now I noticed, that of course the method that queries the database via greenDAO is invoked every time I rotate the activity or come back to it from another activity. That's pretty clear, since I'm calling that method from `onCreate`.

My question is: is it best practice to do this like I'm doing it (requery DAO every time) or should I make my objects parcelable and save the list I have in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onRestore` instead of requerying DAO?

Comment: Probably neither. Use some sort of in-memory cache. I haven't used greenDAO, but if there isn't one built-in, create one. Instance state is for identifying information (that isn't part of the `Intent`) and for transient information (e.g., partially-completed forms that you do not want to commit to persistent storage).

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, their docs say about queries and sessions: `A side effect of this is some kind of entity “caching”. If an entity object is still around in memory (greenDAO uses weak references here), the entity is not constructed again. Also, greenDAO performs no database query to update the entity values. Instead, the object is returned “immediately” from the session cache`, so there does seem to be some kind of caching already.

Comment: "best practice" is debatable but I second @CommonsWare comment. savedInstanceState for a `state` of that specific `instance`, which could be some form data or some state machine. The DB results is not part of that state and should not be saved there. I also never used greenDao, but in case it doesn't cache you could possibly use LruCache or WeakReference. **edit:** I saw your comment, so if greenDao already caches, just keep your code the way it is

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. I guess I'll leave things as they are for now and later do checks with lots of data (which won't occur for my kind of app) just to see what the performance impact is.

Comment: btw in step 3 you are loading all the items (so you need to go async), why not to use `listLazy`?

Comment: @pspink what's the huge difference between the way I'm doing it and `listLazy`?

Comment: see [here](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Query_and_LazyList) for more info, [this](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/blob/master/examples/twitter/TwitterClient/src/com/birbit/android/jobqueue/examples/twitter/adapters/LazyListAdapter.java) adapter is for a `ListView` but adopting it to `RecyclerView` should not take more than 15 minutes

Comment: @pskink, please note that even if `LazyList` is used, it doesn't obviate a need for async query. `LazyList` just optimizes memory usage, but the initial query still need to be done on BG thread.

Comment: @Vasiliy not always, GreenDAO is based on std `SQLiteCursor`s the same `Cursor` implementation which is typically passed to `CursorAdapter`, when using `CursorAdapter` with a large data set (more than one can keep in one `CursorWindow`) your sqlite data is read on the UI thread but still you dont see any hiccups

Comment: @pskink, `CursorAdapter` should receive `SQLiteCursor` (which is the result of query operation) from somewhere, right? For example, it can get it from `CursorLoader`. Note that `CursorLoader` performs the query on background thread. This is what I'm saying - irrespective to whether you read the entire `Cursor` at once, or perform lazy-loading, in both cases the initial query should still be executed in bg thread.

Comment: @Vasiliy even if you load the `SQLiteCursor` via `CursorLoader` the data can be read on the UI thread: note that `SQLiteCursor` extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` and for large data sets the `CursorWindow` can be filled as you scroll your `ListView` on the UI thread, see `SQLiteCursor` source code, method `onMove` that calls `fillWindow` which fills the `CursorWindow` on demand

Comment: @pskink, I'm not sure you understand what I'm saying, because you talk about `SQLiteCursor` API, while I'm talking about the way you obtain a reference to this object. Are you suggesting that it is OK to obtain a reference to `SQLiteCursor` by querying the database on UI thread? Because all I'm saying is that your previous comment is misleading - usage of `LazyList` won't obviate the need for async query. I think we shall end this discussion - interested readers have enough text to digest the intent )

Comment: Well, AFAIK the Android docs on SQLite state that `getReadableDatabase` and `getWritableDatabase` should not be called on the main thread as they are potentially long operations. As greenDAO at some point needs to call them I suppose that the question whether or not to fetch the data on a different thread is answered by the Android docs in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, I tend to agree with your opinion on that subject. BTW, you might be surprised, but GreenDAO official position on that subject is not that specific. See this issue I filed some time ago: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is completely valid and you don't need to save the queried data in `onSaveInstanceState()`, use in-memory cache, or any other optimization (even if GreenDAO wouldn't have internal cache).

In fact, you're more than all-right because you perform the query asynchronously - GreenDAO's creators kind of claim that the queries can be executed on UI thread in most cases (which I find hard to agree with).

I would also suggest that you perform data query in `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`. I personally think that `onCreate()` should be used only for operations you would otherwise perform in the constructor (e.g. fields initializations). Another reason to perform this query in `onStart()` is that if the user leaves your application for a long time and then gets back to it, the data might get outdated (e.g. due to background syncs by `SyncAdapter`) and you'll want to refresh it.

The last piece that you might want to add is "data change notifications". You will want this mechanism to be in place if the data that you query and display to the user can change without user's interaction (e.g. due to background syncs by `SyncAdapter`). The concept is simple - `Activity` registers for notifications about data change in `onCreate()`, and if notification received you perform re-query in order to make sure that the user sees an up-to-date data.

I can't claim that the above are "best practices", but they are good practices that work well.

**Lazy list:**

As @pskink suggested in his comment, you could also employ `LazyList`. Be aware, though, that it doesn't obviate a need for async query of data. Usage of `LazyList` allows you to perform the query as usual, but load the results into memory in on-demand way. This might be useful if you expect the query to produce lots of data.

In my opinion, however, one should optimize the code only if actual performance problem is being observed. So, unless you know ahead of time that a particular query produces thousands of results, I say you don't need `LazyList`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Due to the nature of my app it is not possible that new entries are created without user interaction. What I'll add is some sort of event bus (Otto?) to be safe. As I'm new to greenDAO I'm not sure whether data change notifications are possible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar To my best knowledge, GreenDAO doesn't support data change notifications. As for event bus, my favorite is GreenRobot's one (the same company that released GreenDAO). But if data can't be changed without user's interactions with the same device, then, maybe, you don't even need data change notifications... Up to you

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, I also added a paragraph about `LazyList` (which @pskink mentioned in comments)